# How to establish a VPN connection without using my DNS

Tags: proxy, dns, vpn, ipv4

Is there any way for me to connect to a VPN without having it use my DNS? My internet provider where im connected can only use the DNS to connect to a separate server, which then connects to the internet as the router only interacts with that server, so if I change my DNS, my connection instantly stops working.

Is there any service that connects to a server without DNS as a VPN, or even some way to set up a proxy to go to another server after it interacts with my DNS?

Tried Changing DNS, no connection using cloudflare or google DNS servers (1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8), Hotspot Shield VPN wouldn't connect, VPN from my home network wouldn't connect.

Answer (score 1):

So, your ISP allows DNS traffic only to its server. And you want to by-pass this limitation.

**Solution 1: SSH Proxy**

```
ssh -D 5000 user@host
```

Now, you can set your applications to use proxy on `socks5://localhost:5000`

You must set "Proxy DNS on socks5"

This proxy goes throught the SSH server

Of course you need SSH server somewhere to connect to.

**Solution 2: DNS over HTTPS**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dnss.1.html

It should work because your DNS packages go as HTTPS packages.

**Solution 3: VPN or other services like nordvpn**

It should work also since packages go encrypted to the VPN.

Actually, VPN should work without your ISP DNS as long as **you connect to the VPN IP address** instead the hostname.

**Finally**

Solution 2 seems to be the only one you are able to perform without external services.